# CSS layout with fixed and liquid columns

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout, liquid-layout

I'm having a problem creating a layout that's partly liquid. The layout has to have 100% width and height but it shouldn't have scrollbars (overflow: hidden;).

[image]

On the image above shows what I'm trying to achieve. As you can see:

1. The header has to be fixed - 110px with 100% width.
2. Two divs wrapped via a container div. The blue one needs to be with fixed width 130px & 100% height, while the green one needs to be with liquid width and 100% height.

Here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0px;
            color: white;
        }
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .spacer {
            clear: both;
        }

        #header {
            background: black;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            float: left;
        }

        #content {
            height: 88%;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #left {
            background: #1664a0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100px;
            float: left;
        }

        #right {
            background: #4aa016;
            height: 100%;
            float: left;
            width: 91%;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
    My Header
</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="left">Left container</div>
    <div id="right">Right container</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

There are a couple of problems with this code:

1. It doesn't work on various resolutions (800x600,1024x768, 1280x1024 and etc)
2. The "content" div doesn't always fill the page to the end.
3. The green div would go below the blue one if you resize the page to lower resolutions.

I guess I might be doing something **TERRIBLY** wrong here but I'm not a designer so is there somebody who could point me to "the right way" of solving this problem?

Comment: Why are you `float`ing the `#header` ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/bmqPV/2/

you have the left set to 100px and the right to 91%, so if 100px is greater than 9% it will go to the next line.

EDIT, here is a new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bmqPV/4/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0px;
            color: white;
        }
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .spacer {
            clear: both;
        }

        #header {
            background: black;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            z-index:3;
        }

        #content {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #left {
            background: #1664a0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100px;
            float: left;
        }

        #right {
            background: #4aa016;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #wrapper
        {
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;}
        .contentcontainer {
            padding-top:100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        My Header
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="left">
            <div class="contentcontainer">Left container</div>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <div class="contentcontainer">Right container</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: ya I updated it in firebug not in fiddle, so I had to repost, sorry

Comment: Wow !! Thanks! This fixes the right column problem! Is there a way to remove the scrollbar that comes when you resize to lower resolutions? I'm pretty sure it comes because of `#content{height: 88%;}` but I can't figure out how to set `#content` to fill the page otherwise?

Comment: @tftd, you can always put `overflow: hidden` in `html, body`, but it depends on how you want the content to behave when its container is too small.

Comment: @JeffB I was reading about that in a couple of tutorials and people suggested setting `min-width`/`min-height` to fix the problem. I hope that's a right thing to do?

Comment: Yes min-height and min-width will help if you don't want the site to go smaller than a certain size.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! This definitely works fine even in IE!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your result through a simple **CSS** with defining positions in **#content** & **#right** for better understanding please see the simple code:-

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0px;
            color: white;
        }
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }


        #header {
            background: black;
            height: 100px;
        }

        #content {
           width:100%;
           border:5px solid red;
           overflow:hidden;
           position:relative;

        }

        #left {
            background: #1664a0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 130px;
            float: left;
        }

        #right {
            background: #4aa016;
            height: 100%;
            float: left;
            width:100%;
            position:absolute;
            margin-left:130px;
        }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    My Header
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div id="left">Left container</div>
    <div id="right">Right container</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**see the demo:-** http://jsbin.com/ajasey/17/edit